# Return value error

Tags: python

I am writing the code to calculate the balance of the salary.I have used a function called balance. But I am getting an error while returning the value.

```
print("WELCOME TO SALARY-BALANCE CALCULATOR")

def balance(salary,expense,bills):
    b=salary-expense-bills
    return b

print("Enter your salary :")
sal=input()

exp=input("Enter your personal expense ")
bil=input("Enter the bills amount")

bal=balance(sal,exp,bil)
print("The balance amount is : %d"%bal)
```

After running above code, I getting following error.

```
line 13, in <module>
  bal=balance(sal,exp,bil)
line 5, in balance
  b=salary-expense-bills
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Can anyone tell where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Chances are you are using Python3 where `input` returns a string.

Comment: try `int(input("..."))`

Comment: Can you please tell us on which python version you're trying to run the script?

Comment: Sorry.I forgot to mention the version. I am using python 3.6.1

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that input returns a string so you need to convert the string to float like the following (and maybe add some input validation throw an error if a string is entered instead of a number)

```
print("WELCOME TO SALARY-BALANCE CALCULATOR")

def balance(salary,expense,bills):
    b=salary-expense-bills
    return b

print("Enter your salary :")
sal= float(input())

exp= float(input("Enter your personal expense "))
bil= float(input("Enter the bills amount"))

bal=balance(sal,exp,bil)
print("The balance amount is : %f" % bal)
```

the best practice is to write a funciton that does the parsing like:

```
def parse_input_number( string ):
    try:
        return float(string)
    except Exception as error:
        print('the input is not a valid number')
```

Comment: OP would probably be better printing without a format string: `print("The balance amount is :", bal)`

Comment: The parsing function does not do the right thing in this case, since it will return None and continue, raising an exception in an unrelated place.

Comment: *the best practice is to write a funciton that does the parsing*, without an example of how to use this, it's pretty hard to discern for a beginner, I'd also disagree that this a "best practice" in python. You'd end up returning None which would give you weird errors later.

Comment: Also, if it is Python2, it is the wrong thing to do, and should be `raw_input` instead.

Comment: @Elazar if it were python2 the two `input()` lines would have evaluated to `float`s and the original error would not have occurred. I think it's safe to add a python3 tag

Comment: @RyanHaining sure, but there is an example here that "demonstrates" python2. It shouldn't.

Comment: @Elazar oh yes of course, missed that edit. **Definitely change that rachid**, either remove it or explain why you should **never** do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
print("WELCOME TO SALARY-BALANCE CALCULATOR")

def balance(salary,expense,bills):
    b=salary-expense-bills
    return b

print("Enter your salary :")
sal=int(input())

exp=int(input("Enter your personal expense "))
bil=int(input("Enter the bills amount"))

bal=balance(sal,exp,bil)
print("The balance amount is : %d"%bal)
```

Comment: answers should include an explanation of the problem and solution, not just code

Comment: Thank you for help. It worked. I actually made the error in datatypes.